# Email notification to a particular address if a specific product is purchased in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am using the woocommerce plugin in my Wordpress website. I am wondering how can I send an email notification to a specific address email if **product A** is purchased by customer.

How to send an email notification to a specific address when a specific product is purchased in Woocommerce?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below will add a custom defined email recipient to New Email Notification When a specific defined product Id is found in order items:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'conditional_recipient_new_email_notification', 15, 2 );
function conditional_recipient_new_email_notification( $recipient, $order ) {
    if( is_admin() ) return $recipient; // (Mandatory to avoid backend errors)

    ## --- YOUR SETTINGS (below) --- ##

    $targeted_id = 37; // HERE define your targeted product ID
    $addr_email  = 'name@domain.com'; // Here the additional recipient

    // Loop through orders items
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        if( $item->get_variation_id() == $targeted_id || $item->get_product_id() == $targeted_id ){
            $recipient .= ', ' . $addr_email; 
            break; // Found and added - We stop the loop
        }
    }

    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: this worked, however if i want to validate multiple product ID's how can i do that

Comment: the code works perfect but take care about the emails could be tagged as spam. Tested using a gmail account as the additional recipent and did not work. In my testing enviroment a used contacto@creandowp.es as de admin and victor.calderon@creandowp.es as the additional recipient email and worked. See more at woocommerce Email FAQ https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/email-faq/

Comment: More details about testing with gmail account, the additional recipent email was sent to gmail and received two hours later so gmail also works but takes some time.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_product_purchase_notification');
function send_product_purchase_notification($orderId)
{
    $order = new WC_Order($orderId);
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
        $product_id = (is_object($item)) ? $item->get_product_id() : $item['product_id'];
        if ($product_id == 1234) {
            $custom_massage = 'Custom email content';
            wp_mail('name@domain.com', 'Product #' . $product_id . ' has been purchased', $custom_massage);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the official [WooCommerce Advanced Notifications extension](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/advanced-notifications/) to generate an advanced notification to send an email to a specific person.