# Need email notification in Woocommerce for multiple specific products to different emails that includes order number

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, notifications

So for each product in my store, when the product is purchased, I would like an additional notification email that includes the order id in the subject to an email address unique for each product. I have found some solutions on here however it looks like I can only use it for one product on my site.

I have tried the 2 codes from this question [Email notification to a particular address if a specific product is purchased in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577659/email-notification-to-a-particular-address-if-a-specific-product-is-purchased-in)

but the issue is that I cannot duplicate this for multiple products.

Any and all help is appreciated.